# MySQL FROM clause with multiple arguments and a space?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Basically, I'm trying to do the same thing as the person asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114781/join-multiple-columns-from-one-table-to-single-column-from-another-table) but the first anwser by 'aF' uses FROM in a way I've never seen.

```
SELECT 
    t1.team_name as team1, 
    t2.team_name as team2, 
    t.team_1, t.team_2
FROM trades t
INNER JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id = t.team_1
INNER JOIN teams t2 ON t2.id = t.team_2;
```

I've never seen a FROM statement with two arguments after it and just a space between them, and it's making it difficult to understand the answer. What does it mean?

Comment: It's called a table alias: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php

Answer (score 2):

It's a short form for `FROM trades AS t`. It's an alias, so you don't have to write the whole table name again and again. And of course to distinguish the tables when you join the same table twice.

Answer (score 1):

Many SQL interpreters can use the syntax `FROM table t` instead of `FROM table as t`. They work exactly the same way.

As an aside, this works in `SELECT` statements, and in `JOIN` as well.