# Join multiple columns from one data frame to single column from another without multiple join operation, in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to match multiple columns from one data frame (df) to to a multiple language dictionary (df_label) and extract the the corresponding labels for each column.
Note: This is not a duplcate question of [Join multiple columns from one table to single column from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114781/join-multiple-columns-from-one-table-to-single-column-from-another-table)

The following is an example of df and df_label dataframes and the desired output

```
  df                df_label                       output
+---+---+       +---+-----+----+        +---+---+------+------+------+
|  s|  o|       |  e| name|lang|        |  s|  o|s_name|o_name|  lang|
+---+---+       +---+-----+----+        +---+---+------+------+------+
| s1| o1|       | s1|s1_en|  en|        | s2| o1| s2_fr| o1_fr|    fr|
| s1| o3|       | s1|s1_fr|  fr|        | s1| o1| s1_fr| o1_fr|    fr|
| s2| o1|       | s2|s2_fr|  fr|        | s1| o1| s1_en| o1_en|    en|
| s2| o2|       | o1|o1_fr|  fr|        | s2| o2| s2_fr| o2_fr|    fr|
+---+---+       | o1|o1_en|  en|        +---+---+------+------+------+
                | o2|o2_fr|  fr|
                +---+-----+----+
```

In other words I want match both columns ***[s,o]*** from df with column ***e*** from df_label and find their corresponding labels in different languages as shown above.

The multi-lang dictionary( df_label) is huge and columns ***[s,o]*** have many duplicates, so two join operations is highly inefficient.

***Is there any way that could be achieved without multiple joins?***

FYI, this is what I did using multiple joins but I really don't like it.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('s1','o1'),('s1','o3'),('s2','o1'),('s2','o2')]).toDF('s','o')
df_label = spark.createDataFrame([('s1','s1_en','en'),('s1','s1_fr','fr'),('s2','s2_fr','fr'),('o1','o1_fr','fr'),('o1','o1_en','en'),('o2','o2_fr','fr')]).toDF('e','name','lang')
df = df.join(df_label,col('s')==col('e')).drop('e').withColumnRenamed('name','s_name').withColumnRenamed('lang','s_lang')
df = df.join(df_label,col('o')==col('e')).drop('e').withColumnRenamed('name','o_name').select('s','o','s_name','o_name','s_lang','o','o_name','lang').withColumnRenamed('lang','o_lang').filter(col('o_lang')==col('s_lang')).drop('s_lang')
```

Comment: I think first you can increase the performance by getting rid of your last filter. Your last line could be rewritten to: `df.join(df_label,[(col('o')==col('e')) & (col('s_lang')==col('lang'))]).drop('e').withColumnRenamed('name','o_name').select('s','o','s_name','o_name','lang')` and it should yield the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on what [gaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3815538/gaw) suggested, this is my proposed solution
The approach was to use only one join but then use a conditional aggregate collect_list to check whether the match was for **s** column or **o** column.

```
df = = spark.createDataFrame([('s1','o1'),('s1','o3'),('s2','o1'),('s2','o2')]).toDF('s','o')
df_label = spark.createDataFrame([('s1','s1_en','en'),('s1','s1_fr','fr'),('s2','s2_fr','fr'),('o1','o1_fr','fr'),('o1','o1_en','en'),('o2','o2_fr','fr')]).toDF('e','name','lang')

df.join(df_label,(col('e')== col('s')) | (col('e') == col('o'))) \
.groupBy(['s','o','lang']) \
.agg(collect_list(when(col('e')==col('s'),col('name'))).alias('s_name')\
,collect_list(when(col('e')==col('o'),col('name'))).alias('o_name')) \
.withColumn('s_name',explode('s_name')).withColumn('o_name',explode('o_name')).show()

    +---+---+----+------+------+
    |  s|  o|lang|s_name|o_name|
    +---+---+----+------+------+
    | s2| o2|  fr| s2_fr| o2_fr|
    | s1| o1|  en| s1_en| o1_en|
    | s1| o1|  fr| s1_fr| o1_fr|
    | s2| o1|  fr| s2_fr| o1_fr|
    +---+---+----+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a way which works with only one join, but since it uses additional (expensive) operations like `explode` etc. I am not sure if it is faster.
But if you like you could give it a try.

The following code produces the desired output:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame([('s1','o1'),('s1','o3'),('s2','o1'),('s2','o2')]).toDF('s','o')
df_label = spark.createDataFrame([('s1','s1_en','en'),('s1','s1_fr','fr'),('s2','s2_fr','fr'),('o1','o1_fr','fr'),('o1','o1_en','en'),('o2','o2_fr','fr')]).toDF('e','name','lang')
df = df.join(df_label,[(col('s')==col('e')) | \
  (col('o')==col('e'))]).drop('e').\   #combine the two join conditions
  withColumn("o_name",when(col("name").startswith("o"),col("name")).otherwise(None)).\
  withColumn("s_name",when(col("name").startswith("s"),col("name")).otherwise(None)).\ #create the o_name and s_name cols
  groupBy("s","o").agg(collect_list("o_name").alias("o_name"),collect_list("s_name").alias("s_name")).\
  #perform a group to aggregate the required vales
  select("s","o",explode("o_name").alias("o_name"),"s_name").\ # explode the lists from the group to attach it to the correct pairs of o and s
  select("s","o",explode("s_name").alias("s_name"),"o_name").\
  withColumn("o_lang", col("o_name").substr(-2,2)).\
  withColumn("lang", col("s_name").substr(-2,2)).filter(col("o_lang")==col("lang")).drop("o_lang")
  #manually create the o_lang and lang columns
```

Result:

```python
+---+---+------+------+----+
|s  |o  |s_name|o_name|lang|
+---+---+------+------+----+
|s2 |o2 |s2_fr |o2_fr |fr  |
|s2 |o1 |s2_fr |o1_fr |fr  |
|s1 |o1 |s1_fr |o1_fr |fr  |
|s1 |o1 |s1_en |o1_en |en  |
+---+---+------+------+----+
```

Comment: maybe i oversimplified the data in my question. the df_label dictionary will have real dictionary data like {e:s1 , name:London, lang: 'en' } , {e:s1 , name:Londre, lang: 'fr' }  and they dont start with 's' or 'o'